# Can GCC ignore nonexisting directories?

Tags: gcc, linker, g++

I have two projects: mylib and myproj
mylib compiles into a shared object.
myproj uses mylib.
I linking myproj using:

```
g++ -L../../mylib/Release myproj.o -lmylib
```

That works fine on my development machine.

On another machine, mylib.so is located in /usr/local/lib. Therefore there is no need for -L.
It compiles fine without the -L.

But, once I compile it with the same command (with the -L), it responds with

> g++: error: ../../mylib/Release: No such file or directory

I would like myproj to compile on both machines with the same command.
Is there a way to make it ignore non existing directories?

It doesn't seem to care whether a full path doesn't exist, it complains only for relative paths.

Comment: What g++ version are you using on the other machine? I tried this command as an example: ```g++ -L../../foo/bar  main.o -lpthread``` and it links without errors even though the foo/bar directory does not exist

Answer (score -1):

You want to use Makefiles as often as you can since they make things a lot easier. In a defined Makefile you could check for the directory first. It could be sth like this:

```
all: 
   if [ -d "mylib" ]; then 
       g++ -L../../mylib/Release myproj.o -lmylib
   else
       g++  myproj.o -lmylib
   fi
```

Of course you can use Variables like CC, etc. This is just a basic example.

Comment: In a Makefile, each line of a recipe is executed individually in its own subshell. If you want to use a multiline shell comnand, you need to use `\\` line continuations to make the comnand into one logical line.